# How to delete a list of objects in EF6 when the object is detached from the context

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

OK I can delete a single item in EF6 like this:

```
public void DeleteUserGroup(MY_GROUPS ug)
{
    using (var context = new MYConn())
    {
        var entry = context.Entry(ug);
        if (entry.State == EntityState.Detached)
        {
            context.MY_GROUPS.Attach(ug);
        }

        context.MY_GROUPS.Remove(ug);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

If this method changed from passing a single instance of `MY_GROUPS` to a `List<MY_GROUPS>` how would I handle the delete?

Would there be a more efficient way then just doing a `foreach` and setting the state one at a time?

**UPDATE**:
I am already using a similar method as above utilizing the `RemoveRange` method.
However I am getting an error:

> The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the
>   ObjectStateManager.

I'm looking for the best way to attach a list of objects to the context so that I can delete them.

Comment: Don't you have .RemoveRange on your context? If I remember correctly you can give RemoveRange a collection of items you want deleted..

Comment: I do and I am using that.  However I get the error "The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the ObjectStateManager."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be able to remove records, you need to make sure your `ObjectContext` is tracking them. Right now you have detached objects, and your context has no knowledge of them so it's impossible to delete them. One way to remove them is to do like you say, `Attach` all your objects to the context, then delete them. The other way is to fetch the records from the database so you can remove them:

```
//Find all groups in database with an Id that is in your group collection 'ug'
var groups = context.My_Groups.Where(g => ug.Any(u => u.Id == g.Id));
context.My_Groups.RemoveRange(groups);
context.SaveChanges();
```

However, note that even while using `RemoveRange`, a delete command will be send to the database *per* item you want to remove. The only difference between `RemoveRange` and `Remove` is that the first will only call `DetectChanges` once, which can really improve performance.

Comment: Is it a bad practice not letting my ObjectContext tracking them? Basically I have a class and each method creates (then disposes) the context.  I do what I need to do in that method and go about my way.

Comment: Depends on how you got the groups. If you fetched certain groups in one method, dispose context and then pass those materialized groups to another method to remove them, it *is* bad practice. However if you got the groups back as a json result or something from a website, there's not much you can do about it obviously.

Comment: Yes. I have methods that are doing that.  My UI uses POCO's and in my middle layer I am mapping the POCO to/from the db tables.  So my EF class is all creating/disposing contexts.  I'm not convinced that I set it up the best because I now cant reuse existing methods in that class.  IE. In case of delete list I would normally call GetGroupList method return that list and then delete them in my delete method.  Now I half to not call that method and do everything in my delete method.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `RemoveRange`:

```
context.MY_GROUPS.RemoveRange(context.MY_GROUPS.Where(x => x.columnName== "Foo"));
```

You can also use `ForEach` like this:

```
context.MY_GROUPS.Where(x => x.columnName == "Foo").ToList().ForEach(context.DeleteObject);
context.SaveChanges();
```

You could also use [`ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreCommand Method`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.executestorecommand(v=vs.110).aspx) as an another approach for this purpose.

Comment: I do and I am using that. However I get the error "The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the ObjectStateManager."

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over your collection and set `Deleted` state for each

```
groups.ForEach(group => ctx.Entry(group).State = EntityState.Deleted);
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: IMO, this is the proper way to work with disconnected object contexts.

Answer (score 1):

I found this it worked for me. I did it in a loop before calling save changes. I wanted it to create just the delete sql command and it did.

http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entityframework6/delete-disconnected-entity-in-entity-framework.aspx

```
// disconnected entity to be deleted
var student = new Student(){ StudentId = 1 };

using (var context = new SchoolDBEntities())
{
    context.Entry(student).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Deleted;    

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

EntityFramework 6+ has made this a bit easier with .RemoveRange().

```
    public void DeleteUserGroup(List<MY_GROUPS> ug)
    {
        using (var context = new MYConn())
        {
            context.MY_GROUPS.RemoveRange(ug);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I do and I am using that. However I get the error "The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the ObjectStateManager."

Comment: The error occurs on the RemoveRange call.  I need to attach the list to the context in order to remove them.  (See my single delete above)

Comment: I could loop through the list and set the state but I was looking for a more efficient way to handle this scenario.

Comment: I also have the same Issue "The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the ObjectStateManager." When I am going to remove list of the object with the help of RemoveRange() method.

Answer (score 0):

By using the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35868431/6652367) provided by [Alexander Deck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3410196/alexander-derck) where brands is an `IEnumerable`:

```
context.Brands.RemoveRange(context.Brands.Where(cb => brands.Any(b => b.Id == cb.Id)));
```

I got the following error:

> ## Unable to create a constant value of type 'SomeCompany.SomeApp.DB.Entities.Brand'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

And it was solved by converting the Brands `DBSet` to `IEnumerable` with the `AsEnumerable()` extension method:

```
context.Brands.RemoveRange(context.Brands.AsEnumerable().Where(cb => brands.Any(b => b.Id == cb.Id)));
```

That did the trick for me.

Comment: Be aware that calling AsEnumerable() will retrieve the full table "Brands" from the database. This may be acceptable but it depends on your table size...

Comment: Thanks for the advice @GrégoryBourgin, I will for sure use it wisely