# How to use RemoveRange with 1-query-approach Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, crud

I look for a way of executing `RemoveRange()` with 1-query-approach. With `Remove()` method it works like this:

```
public void Delete()
{
    Record record = new Record() {
        id = 1,
        value = 5
    };
    using(SomeContext ctx = new SomeContext()) {
        ctx.Records.Entry(record).State = EntityState.Deleted;
        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

But the same approach doesn't work for `RemoveRange()`. EF documentation says that the method sets each entity to `EntityState.Deleted`. If it would be so as I understand it - this would work:

```
public void DeleteAll()
{
    List<Record> records = new List<Record>() {
        new Record() { id = 1, value = 5 },
        new Record() { id = 2, value = 10 }
    };
    using(SomeContext ctx = new SomeContext()) {
        ctx.Records.RemoveRange(records);
        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

because this works:

```
public void DeleteAll()
{
    List<Record> records = new List<Record>() {
        new Record() { id = 1, value = 5 },
        new Record() { id = 2, value = 10 }
    };
    using(SomeContext ctx = new SomeContext()) {
        foreach(var item in records)
        {
            ctx.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Deleted;
        }
        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

But it doesn't and throws the exception

```
The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the ObjectStateManager.
```

Can I use this method without retrieving all of them from database via separate query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `ctx.Entry(item)` it adds this item to the context tracking and then you can edit it. With `RemoveRange` it does not implicitly add to the data context first and that is why you get the exception.
Try using `AttachRange` before `RemoveRange`

Edit:

Alternative way to do it. This is a bit how `RemoveRange` does it behind the scenes. It first disables `AutoDetectChanges`, removes what it should and then calls `DetectChanges`. Could wrap this in an extension method to make it a one liner again.

```
public void DeleteAll()
{
    List<Record> records = new List<Record>() {
        new Record() { id = 1, value = 5 },
        new Record() { id = 2, value = 10 }
    };
    using(SomeContext ctx = new SomeContext()) {
        ctx.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
        foreach(var item in records)
        {
            ctx.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Deleted;
        }
        ctx.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't find the method in EF Documentation. Do you mean custom method? Will it be fast enough?

Comment: Might be EF Core only method, did not realize it might not be in EF6. Sorry

Comment: Fine, the edit is what I was asking for, is it a food practice? Will it be faster than retrieving collection from database using `ctx.Records.Where(dbr => records.Any(r => r.id == dbr.id));`? Or changing the state does the same? Does it execute query to get every record from database?

Comment: I am not really sure, I think it might do a query to get the `Entry`. But can only be sure if you add query logger and check yourself. If you didnt by monday, I ll check that. Got no EF set up at home :)

Comment: @VitaliiIsaenko Tested it with EF6 and the `Entry` does not create a query to the database. It only queries the db once you call `SaveChanges`. Regarding your question if it is good practice, I would say no. While this reduces the amount of queries, it is also prone to generate errors. If you set an Entry that does not exist in the db to deleted, a concurrency exception is thrown. I would always get entries from the db and then delete.

Answer (score 0):

As I found your entity-collection is detached(as you creating it there) so objectContext not tracking it. You may need to attach it. you can do this as below:

```
//Find all records in database with an id that is in your record collection 
var recordsToBeDeleted = ctx.Records.Where(dbr => records.Any(r => r.id == dbr.id));
ctx.Records.RemoveRange(recordsToBeDeleted);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Solution taken from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35868431/1589885)

Comment: Thank you, but this requires execute a query to database before removing. I know exactly that these objects exist in database so I'd like to delete records without retrieving them first.