# EF Core Same TABLE TWO ACTIONS (Remove item + update remaining ones)

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I have a weird situation.

I have a list from where I need to remove an item from the DB, then all remaining ones I need to just increment and update them.

I use.AsNoTracking() on the list filtering but I cannot perform the above actions thought.
Keeps telling me that "
"The property 'ListNumber' on entity type 'LIST' is part of a key and so cannot be modified or marked as modified. To change the principal of an existing entity with an identifying foreign key first delete the dependent and invoke 'SaveChanges' then associate the dependent with the new principal."

I've tried also to build 1 method for remove and 1 for update the remaining items and call them from the controller (the first one is the remove then the second one is the update) but the same result.

Anyone can help me out because I'm stuck I would highly appreciate a clear example or approach on how I can deal with the above situation.

Thank you in advance.

This is how I call the methods from the controller

```
await _repo.RemoveFromList("1234", "1");
await _repo.ResetList("1234");
```

Below are the methods I'm using, remove one works but when I'm using the reset list I got an exception

```
public async Task RemoveFromList(string listNumber, string listItem)
        {
            try
            {
                var entity = await _context.LIST.Where(x => x.ListNumber == listNumber && x.ListItem == listItem).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
                _context.LIST.Remove(entity);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

public async Task ResetList(string listNumber)
        {
            try
            {
                var entities = await _context.LIST.AsQueryable().Where(x => ListNumber== listNumber).ToListAsync();
                var startFrom = 1;
                foreach (var en in entities)
                {
                    en.NewListNumber = startFrom.ToString().PadLeft(3, '0');
                    startFrom++;
                    _context.LIST.Update(en);
                }

                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Since you are using AsNoTracking() the problem could be that the objects you are trying to update are detached, so EF can not track changes on them. The question is do you need to use AsNoTracking?. Probably you want to check this answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35868066/how-to-delete-a-list-of-objects-in-ef6-when-the-object-is-detached-from-the-cont

Comment: It could be any number of reasons,  post the relevant code from your implementatrion

Comment: @Juan I've updated the code, please take a look. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @E-Bat Done, please see above

Comment: why you use AsNoTracking()? try to remove AsNoTracking or if it is necessary to use that,  attach the entity as modified and deleted.

Comment: @Jafarashrafi sorry it did not work.

Comment: how you resolve your context in start up. can you give your code sample? @C.Razvan

Comment: @Jafarashrafi please see here: `code` services.AddDbContext<ProjectContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("ProjectContext")));


            var dbOptions = services.BuildServiceProvider()
                      .GetRequiredService<DbContextOptions<ProjectContext>>();
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                using (var dbContext = new ProjectContext(dbOptions))
                {
                    var model = dbContext.Model; //force the model creation
                }
            });`code`

Comment: @C.Razvan You say that the first method now works, good. About the second method failing, take a look at the exception(or inner exceptions if available) and let us know

Comment: I managed to get it work like below. 'code' var updateList = await _context.UpdateLists.FindAsync(id);
                _context.UpdateLists.Remove(updateList);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                var resetAllRows = await _context.UpdateLists.ToListAsync();
                var row = 1;
                foreach (var item in resetAllRows)
                {
                    item.ListRow = row.ToString();
                    row++;
                    _context.Update(item);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync(); 'code'